# "Dock" a div element above the other on onClick() event

Tags: javascript, html, css

so how do I do this? I need to set/dock a div element (containing some other divs & form objects) above the other Div. The docking div serves as some sort of inputbox dialog which should emerge right above an element you click on, in my case, I set the `onClick()` event on a...

`Click <span onClick="showInputbox()">here</span> to set value` element.

Not sure if this is achievable using CSS only, but I would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit: I'm actually having problem with the **positioning**: Putting an element (I should say) **above** the other (the label or spanned text element), not so much about showing-hiding the element.

As for the script:

```
function showInputbox(){
var txt = document.getElementById("txtHere").style;
var dlgInput = document.getElementById("dlgInput").style;

dlgInput.top = txt.top + dlgInput.height;
dlgInput.left = txt.left;
dlgInput.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Which won't work, I mean, the `.top` and `.left` always shows `null`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: show your script, html, css and everything you had

Comment: What is the relation between those 2 `divs`? Is one the parent of the other, is one a sibling of the other, they are totally unrelated in HTML ?

Comment: Thanks for your clear question. So the 2 divs have the same parent. But what do you mean by "unrelated" in HTML? I tried uploading a picture but it wont let me. But here's what I've just tried:
`function showInputbox(){
var o = document.getElementById("txtHere").style; //the <span> element
var b = document.getElementById("dlgInput").style;

b.top = a.top + b.height;
b.left = a.left;
}`

and it didn't seem to work...

Comment: Ok, that means that they are siblings. By unrelated I meant that they have no common immediate parent.

Comment: I posted an answer based on what you told us. Without a clear HTML structure this is as much as we can do, but answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to position two sibling `divs` one above the other, you can use the fact that they have the same parent and do the positioning with CSS.

The first example can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GLf4X/1/).
What this does:

- the HTML is a simple structure as you said with 2 `divs` with a common parent.
- in the CSS, I give a width and height to both `divs` and a background. Also, I set the `display` for the first `div` that should be hidden at the beginning as `none`.
- I also set the hidden `div` as `position:absolute`. This allows me to use things like `bottom`, `left`, `right`, `top`.
- you can see that I added `position:relative` to the parent element. I did this because `position:absolute` will position relative to the first parent element that has a `position` of `relative` or `absolute`.
- than I use jQuery library to add the `onClick()` event that will add `display:block` to the hidden `div` when the second `div` is clicked.
- **MAKE SURE** you add the `onClick()` event when the DOM has fully loaded (DomReady, is selected in the jsFiddle posted, with jQuery you have the `ready` event).

Note: the jQuery part can be done with only javascript too, but I recommend to use it since it saves a lot of working-time and it is really common.

### Update:

http://jsfiddle.net/GLf4X/5/

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
    </div>
    <div id="child3">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#child1{
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    background:#333;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100%;
}

#child2{
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    background:#666;
    margin-bottom:100px;
}

#child3{
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    background:#999;
}

#parent{
    margin:60px auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function getOffset( el ) {
    var offset = { top: 0, left:0 };
    if( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
        offset.left = el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        offset.top = el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
    }
    return offset;
}

function displayAboveElement(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    var divToShow = document.getElementById('child1'),
        clickTarget = event.target;
        offset = getOffset(clickTarget);
    divToShow.style.display = 'block';
    console.log(clickTarget.style);
    divToShow.style.top = (offset.top - clickTarget.clientHeight) + 'px';
    divToShow.style.left = offset.left + 'px';
}

document.getElementById('child2').onclick = displayAboveElement;

document.getElementById('child3').onclick = displayAboveElement;
```

What was your problem:

- you are trying to read `left` and `top` from an element that doesn't have it set. That is why they are null.
- `left` and `top` are only valid for `position:absolute` elements.
- an element's `style` returns the inline style attributes as far as I know and you don't want that I think.

As you can see, there are a lot of things to consider when writing javascript without a library (also, there are 4-5 browsers that you must support and code that works in one browser may not work in the other). This is why I recommended using a library like jQuery.

What I did:

- calculated the offset top and left for the clicked element relative to its direct parent.
- added those value as inline style to the `div` that has to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please provide the jQuery-less script?

Edit: The example you posted was actually about stacking an element on top of the other, which is not what I want, I need it the appear right "above" the <span>here</span> element.

Comment: I edited the question a bit, please have a look and I really hope it's clearer this time

Comment: I finally got home so I updated my answer with what you want. Hope it helped you to learn.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Really appreciate you taking the time, 'twas very clear though I might still need some time to learn some things there as a beginner. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't worry, where there is will to do it, there is time.